# Difference between $UserProfileManager. - RemoveUserProfile() and RemoveProfile()

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, userprofilemanager

you can see my question in the title.

One more another question to this situation:
Do any of you know, what happens after the MySite-CleanUp-Job runs?
In my company there are a lot of users with the "bDelete"-Flag which are still working with their users on the farm.
Now i want to delete the "unused"-Profiles manually via PS-Script. 
I found a lot of solutions:

- Delete via script from every Site (foreach - site)
- RemoveUserProfile()
- RemoveProfile()
- PersonalSite.Delete()

i am a little bit confused, which one i need to use?!
Thanks in advance!!

Leon

Answer (score 0):

[**UserProfileManager.RemoveUserProfile Method**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.removeuserprofile?view=sharepoint-server): Removes the user profile, quick links, and alert data from the user profile database.

**[UserProfileManager.RemoveProfile(ProfileBase) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.removeprofile?view=sharepoint-server)**: Removes the specified user profile from the database.

If you want to delete inactive users in user profiles, we can use the PowerShell below to achieve it.

```
#PowerShell Script – Delete Inactive User Profiles – SharePoint 2010/2013

#The scripts is distributet "as-is." Use it on your own risk. The author give no warranties, guarantees or conditions.

if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$site = Get-SPSite "<site url>"
$ctx = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$pm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ctx)

$ProfileDB = Get-SPDatabase | ? { $_.Type -eq "Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileDatabase"}

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $ProfileDB.DatabaseConnectionString
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select NTName,RecordId from UserProfile_Full where bDeleted=1″
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()

Write-host "Total Count: " $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count
Write-Host "Following Inactive Accounts will be deleted !"

foreach($user in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   write-host "Planning to delete :" $user["NTName"] -ForegroundColor Green
   $profile = $pm.GetProfile($user["RecordId"])
    #To enable delete operation remove comment out for below line
    #$pm.RemoveProfile($profile)
    #write-host $user["NTName"] is deleted!!! -ForegroundColor Red
}
write-host "Operation Completed !"
```

Refer to: [Delete inactive users in user profiles](https://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2016/03/30/delete-inactive-users-in-user-profiles/)

The complete guide to user profile cleanup, you can refer to the article below.

[SharePoint: The complete guide to user profile cleanup](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/spjr/2018/04/08/sharepoint-the-complete-guide-to-user-profile-cleanup-part-3-2013/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
So for me it sounds like that "...RemoveProfile()" delete the user from every Database? It is like a full clean-Up from the system?
So its like a manual/scripting way/replacement for the Cleanup-Job?

Because the description of the method from Microsoft is not very clear.